# Can't find Axis 2 Web services facet

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I'm trying to create an Axis2 web service on OS X Yosemite using Eclipse Luna (64bit) with a running Tomcat v7.0 server. When i go to **New** > **Dynamic web project** > **Modify** (under **Configuration**), Axis2 web services is not in the list of facets. I have followed [this tutorial](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/create-java-web-service-in-eclipse_8.html) but I'm stuck at this level [here](https://puu.sh/bFqnt/5d357f6d81.png):

[image: I'm stuck at this level]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just noticed OS X Yosemite does not fully support all the Java EE functions (including Axis2 web services).